# SFTP batch...cancel command if previous command fails

Tags: unix, batch-file, sftp

I am running an SFTP batch to get a series of files from one unix server to another. I have a shell script that builds the batch files like:

```
cd path

get filename

cd path

get filename
```

and more.

Is there a way within SFTP to NOT run a get command if the preceding cd command fails, but keep running the rest of the batch?

To be clear, I do NOT want to terminate the whole SFTP batch, just the one get command if it's related cd command does not work.

Comment: I would use a mixture of `remDir=$(ssh user@remote 'cd path; echo $PWD')`, test that remDir has the value you expect, then `scp file user@remote/$remDir`. Too much for a comment. You have some work ahead of you. Tell you manager there is no magic bullet for safe file transfer that is also painless. Good luck.

Comment: I build the sftp batch file in a ksh script...I'm already looping the list to build the batch file, so it wouldn't be a problem to check each path in the existing loop before adding them to the batch file...I was just hoping to handle it from within sftp...the script is already long enough as it is.

Comment: `ftp` clients are notoriously varied animals. I'm not so sure about `sftp` clients. Did you do `man sftp` and read the section on `-b batchfile`? Mine says "`Termination on error can be suppressed on a command by command basis by prefixing the command with a '-' character (for example, -rm /tmp/blah*)."`. But I don't see anything like shell conditionals. YRMV. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

After each cd check error code, if it is 0, everything is fine. If not, some error occured in last command...

Like:

```
cd directory
if [!$?]
then
   get something
fi
```

Comment: the O.P. is referring to cmds internal to `sftp`. You can't test the return status of any cmds in `sftp`. (The question is not clear). Good luck to all.

Comment: Oh... i think there is no way to check it out on sftp client.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry if I was not clear...I need to be able to do this from within sftp itself.  Since it seems this is not possible, I will research alternatives.  Thank you.